# Count boolean in mysql

Tags: mysql

My database has a layout like this:

| StudentID | ActivityNumber | Payed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 0 |

The Payed column is a boolean to look if a perseon has payed yes or no and not to look how much he/she payed
now as you see nobody payed for activity 2 but if i use this command

```
SELECT ActivityNumber, COUNT(*) as TimesPayed
FROM Registration
WHERE Payed = 1
GROUP BY ActivityNumber
```

MySQL doesn't show ActivityNumber 2 in the results because the count is 0 but I want to show that the count is 0 and I don't know how because if i delete the WHERE clause it will count it as 1 and not 0

The result i expect is this:

| ActivityNumber | TimesPayed |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 |

Comment: `WHERE payed = 1` .... it's in english

Comment: cody, could you elaborate more like.. by providing expected result? also, it seems like `payed` doesnt matter much by your description, perhaps you were looking for `group by` and `sum` instead?

Comment: i edited my question i hope it is more understandable now

Comment: `select ActivityNumber, sum(Payed) from Registration group by ActivityNumber`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional `SUM`.

Query -

```
SELECT ActivityNumber, sum( case when payed = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) as TimesPayed
FROM Registration
group by ActivityNumber
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jFm1wuGfM6V8AfyLs2Zd6/0)